# (Hibernate )how to convert hbm files to JPA annotation based classes?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, hbm

Can any one tell me how to convert .hbm files to annotated based classes .
I was trained in annotation based hibernate but in project they were using hbm files .Its really hard to understand .

I really appreciate if any one share some tutorial on hbm file creations .

Regards,
sravan